# Article about primes.(Revised)

Tags: prime-numbers, intuition

I'm trying to write a article about primes, and I'm curious whether I can really involve other topics (like complex numbers) and relate them to observe peculiar properties of primes. Or can I try using matrices (seems absurd, but possible, I guess)?

I thought something about determinants and primes. There's a square matrix $M\in M_{n\times n}\left(\Bbb{N}\right)$ with $n > 2$ such that $\det M = p$ is prime. What conditions on the elements or matrix would give prime determinant? I was just trying out for $3\times 3$ matrices. I used some of the obvious types of primes as a determinant (for example, the determinant has to be a Mersenne Prime or Fermat Prime). Can someone really help on this? What conditions on the elements of an $n\times n$ matrix would guarantee that the determinant is a prime?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime-numbers

Comment: Oh come on! I want the ideas on how I can relate Matrix or Complex numbers with primes.

Comment: I like your style, me too!

Comment: Riemann zeta and [random matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix#Number_theory) may interest you...

Comment: Yeah! I have gone through them before posting the stuff.:). And there's a thing called Gaussian integer! That's a whole lot pure complex numbers.

Comment: Gaussian primes might make an interesting essay.

Comment: True. How about connecting matrix and primes? Any possibility?

Comment: You might enjoy forming magic squares whose entries are all distinct primes. Or finding the order of GL$(n,p)$, the group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries coming from the integers modulo a prime $p$.

Comment: "A detailed canonical answer is required"? "I expect suggestions which are not from previous research"??? You expect people to invent, on the spot, brand new relations between primes and other topics, so you can write an article about primes? Hoo, boy!

Comment: Just the suggestions. lol.!  I have made my own research on few things. Just needed techniques which are not trivial.?

Comment: Come on, Gerry! He's sweetening the deal with 50 points rep! Yeah, reminds me of the Dilbert strip where two marketing dudes ask him to invent a Star Trek style cloak of invisibility. They even give him 5 minutes to think about it.

Comment: But seriously. Where is this article supposed to appear? In your blog? Local paper? College journal? Peer reviewed scientific journal. The latter is the default association many regulars have with the word "article" - something with a content **discovered by yourself after painstakingly working on it for a year** (well, anything between a few weeks and 7 years at postdoctoral level).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Oh C'mn. I'm ain't gonna copy stuffs. I want ideas. I have my own too. And the article I'm talking about? I'm not posting it anywhere . I keep it for myself. This ain't any race or anything. I got the idea about combining topics. So, I'm like "Why not try that?".

Answer (score 4):

The $16$ consecutive primes $$31,37,\dots,101$$ can be used to form a magic square with magic constant $258$, the smallest possible for such a $4\times4$ square. Similarly, you can get a $5\times5$ magic square with $25$ consecutive primes and magic constant $313$, a $6\times6$ with consecutive primes and constant $484$, and so on.

What's the smallest possible constant for a $3\times3$ magic square with $9$ consecutive primes?

Comment: No. I haven't tried that. And how did you get the constant?, there must be some algorithm for that.?

Comment: My algorithm is to look it up on the internet.

Comment: Well, that was clever. ;)!.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A073520